# Array inside a dictionary key

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am geting json from server of this format

```
{
"ascii_needed" = 1;
"feed_data" = (
    {
        id = 1593;
         url = “bb”;
        "url_text" = “aa”;
    },
    {
        id = 1593;
         url = “bb”;
        "url_text" = “aa”;
    });
page=10;
"user_id" = 4920;
}
```

I was able to get value of user_id from json using this code

```
[responseObject[@"user_id"] stringValue]
```

How do i loop through all feed_data and store it in an array to pass to another view controller?

Comment: It's already an array.  Just pass `responseObject[@"feed_data"]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
NSDictionary *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [(NSString *) message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];

if (!JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    NSArray *feedDataArray= [JSON objectForKey:@"feed_data"];

 for(NSDictionary *item in feedDataArray) {
      NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"id"]);
      NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"url"]);
      NSLog(@"%@",[item objectForKey:@"url_text"]);

   }
}
```

You can pass feedDataArray to another view controller. You have to create a propery in destination view controller and assign it in prepareForSegue method.